# Handling callbacks in Dart classes

Tags: class, sockets, callback, dart

My dart application it's listening to a socket I want to return the socket reply on the `command(...)` function after it is processed in the `dataHandler` event.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';

class TeamSpeak3{

    Socket socket;
    String command;

    String _ip;
    int _port;



    TeamSpeak3(String ip, int port) {
        this._ip = ip;
        this._port = port;
    }

    Future<int> connect() async {
        await Socket.connect(_ip, _port)
            .then((Socket sock) {
            socket = sock;
            socket.listen(
                dataHandler,
                onError: errorHandler,
                onDone: doneHandler,
                cancelOnError: false);
        }).catchError((AsyncError e) {
            print("Connection failed: $e");
            exit(1);
        });
        socket.done;
        return 1;
    }


    void auth(String name, String pass){
        socket.write("login $name $pass\n");
    }

    void send(String cmd){
        command = cmd;
        socket.write('$cmd\n');
        //return reply from dataHandler
    }

    void dataHandler(data){
        var reply = new String.fromCharCodes(data).trim();
        //return $reply on the send function
    }

    void errorHandler(error, StackTrace trace){
        print(error);
    }

    void doneHandler(){
        print("Connection termiated!");
        socket.destroy();
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which callback do you want to pass to which class or function?

Comment: @creativecreatormaybenot `socket.write` writes something to the socket and than the `dataHandler` process the output, I need to pass that as return value of `send`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't know for sure that the entire response to your send arrives in one packet, so you might not have the entire response.
Let's assume that you do (otherwise you'll have to do more processing in `dataHandler` to collect the response before delivering it).

The canonical way to allow a callback to be called when something has happened in the future, is to return a `Future`. You will also need a way to complete that future, so you create a `Completer` and store it until you need it. Since you can probably do more sends, you need to remember more than one completer. So, all in all, I'd write this as:

```
Queue<Completer<String>> _queue = Queue();

Future<String> send(String cmd){
    socket.writeln(cmd);
    var completer = new Completer<String>();
    _queue.add(completer);
    return completer.future;
}

void _dataHandler(data){
    var reply = new String.fromCharCodes(data).trim();
    // Add some sanity checking here. Make sure you have the entire response before
    // executing the code below.
    _queue.removeFirst().complete(reply);
}
```

(I made `_dataHandler` private because you probably don't want the user calling `send` to alse be able to call `dataHandler`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it gives me this error: `Unhandled exception:
Bad state: No element
#0      ListQueue.removeFirst (dart:collection/queue.dart:793:25)
#1      TeamSpeak3._dataHandler (file:///D:/Documents/PhpstormProjects/TS3Bot/lib/ts3.dart:67:16)`

Comment: Indeed after debugging: `if (_queue.isEmpty){print("Empty") }` it shows that it's empty

Comment: nvm I solved that the issue was that connect too trigger an answer from the server.

Comment: Hi again, I'm having issue calling a function that will trigger another server response inside the data handler ie: Client send to the bot `!help` the bot should reply with `I'm here to help you`. But the behavior it's this: if I call another function inside the call (to get more client info) the first reply get stuck, the second send the reply twice and from the third are fine. The full sourcecode:  https://github.com/Hexer10/TeamSpeak3-Library/blob/master/bin/main.dart#L39